# how to get selected value on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using javascript/jquery and html to get selected anchor tag value and disable its click event  on mouse hover of UL element of html
I am try below code but target not achieved.What should I do ? 
Thanks in advance

**html**

```
  <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all test1"
                role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1;
                top: -15px; left: 115px; display: none; position: relative; width: 300px;">
                <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">City
                    Name</a></li><li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
                        <br>
                    </a></li>
                <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
                    <br>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(".ui-autocomplete").hover(function () {
                $(".ui-autocomplete li").find('a:contains(City Name)').click(function () {
                    $(this).unbind();
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Can we please have a JSFiddle code to work with?

Answer (score 0):

**Problems with your code:**

1. You haven't added the code in ready function.
2. You haven't bound the exact event. There's no getting it.
3. Use `$this = $(this);` instead of `$(this);`, as you are referring a parent element.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this will be a start towards the right direction.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".ui-autocomplete").hover(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $(".ui-autocomplete li:first-child").find('a').click(function () {
      $(this).unbind();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all test1" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: -15px; left: 115px; position: relative; width: 300px;">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">City Name</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
    <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```